# How to get collapsible document blocks inside tables like maple does?

Tags: maple

Back in university time, the first CAS I was introduced to was maple and thus used it extensively for mathematical documentation.

Recently I find myself reading again and want to create extensive notes.

Back in maple days, I used tables a lot to organize ideas and maple allowed its main document blocks to be placed inside its tables with no restriction on nesting the tables inside tables with collapsible blocks inside tables and so on.

Since I have learned Mathematica now, I want to use it for writing notes as well. But I want the similar layout I used to have in maple.

Is there a way to create collapsible blocks inside tables and can tables have cells math, text and code simultaneously inside the tables.

[image]

Also mathematical syntax in maple looks so natural and pleasing. If someone has written a package to make mathematica look more like maple then please share that as well.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The mathematical syntax in the picture you posted appears identical to what you would get with Mathematica. Greek letters, superscripts, subscripts, sum symbols, integral symbols, piecewise symbols, partial differentials, and many other mathematical symbols are all available. Is there a particular example of a difference you had in mind?

Comment: @MassDefect mostly what I need right now is a way to include collapsible blocks inside the tables. Moreover, I hate the sum have its limits in superscript and subscript position rather than over and under-script. Moreover as you put things in xxx-script positions fonts sizes decreases drastically (but this i know how to fix).

Comment: Also Mathematica lacks the notation of pre-superscript and pre-subscript.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help with the tables (which is your main question). There is the ability to add over/underscript and pre-super/subscript though. I couldn't say whether it's as elegant as Maple's version, but they do exist. The buttons in the typesetting assistant you showed are [[2, 3]] and [[3, 3]]. The over/underscript seems to be interpreted correctly as input for the sum symbol, but I don't know what pre-super/subscripts are used for so I'm not sure if they're interpreted as arguments at all. Hopefully someone knows a way to do the table thing though, that looks quite useful!

Comment: `Also mathematical syntax in maple looks so natural and pleasing.` I agree. But only on the screen, when inside the Maple worksheet. But try to export that math to Latex, and it all falls apart, as the Latex output is terrible compared to Mathematica's Latex export.